# can anyone kindly tell me what this shrub is ?

Tags: identification

[image]

can anyone kindly tell me what this shrub is ? THANK YOU IN ADAVANCE !!

Comment: This is not the standard Prunus laurocerasus or Cherry laurel - if its a cherry laurel at all, and I'm not at all sure it is, its Prunus laurocerasus 'rotundifolia', which has much narrower leaves which are toothed on the edges, unlike P. laurocerasus.

Comment: You are so good you are bad, Bamboo!  You can see those leaf margins?    Anyhoo, if those margins are an indication rotundifolia is right.  You can SEE the margins?  What else do you think this could be other than P. laurocerasus...Schip is too narrow of a leaf...rotundifolia (what is the common name for this variety)?  What other plant...?

Comment: ...and now I can see those edges as well.  But...you aren't at all certain about P. laurocerasus...what other plants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be Prunus laurocerasus 'rotundifolia' or Cherry Laurel.

Comment: It isn't though....

Comment: Grins...let's find out what it is that we can agree upon.  I am never going to be able to ID for certain based on photographs.  I do great when I can see the plant, touch the plant, I know the scale, but this ID ing based on pictures, we can only hope to know for sure.  You are far better Bamboo, let me tell you!  So WHAT is this if not P. laurocerasus?  Or some variety of same?  I always feel like I am playing poker and I sit to the left to the dealer, and I threw the opening bid on the table.  Doesn't that help to be able to say what a plant is NOT?  I am fine being wrong and second guessed!

Comment: Possibly a variant of P. laurocerasus, but to be honest, the photos are not clear, can't see proper detail, its like they've been taken through a window or through grime on the camera lens, slightly misty, and don't magnify well, so hard to be certain, they're fairly nondescript, but its just possible to detect the toothed edges to the leaves, and definitely possible to rule out P. laurocerasus, the basic plant, simply from the size, colour and shape of the leaves. Needs better photos...